# Google chrome extension input type="radio"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've done extension, which can turn on/off images and plugins in Google Chrome.
Looks like this:

[screenshot http://les.by/images/Grado/ext.jpg](http://les.by/images/Grado/ext.jpg)

I know how to set settings for images and plugins with JavaScript. And i think that i know how to get settings. I would like "radio" to be checked, when images turned on or off. Help me, please.

Comment: Won't the `checked="checked"` property work on them radios?

Comment: it works. but how to make radio be cheched, if images setting is set to "allow", like in options page of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically set the checked value upon page render.

```
<label for=foo>foo</label>
<input id=foo name=foobar type=radio>
<label for=bar>bar</label>
<input id=bar name=foobar type=radio>​

<script>
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.checked = true;
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GgJP9/